# Initial value problem ODE - "choosing" particular solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I just asked a question about initial value problems but encountered another one immediately.

$ y''(t) - 6y'(t) + 9y(t) = 18 $

$y(0) = 2,  $

$y'(0) = 1  $

The homogenous solution is: $c_1e^{2x} + c_2xe^{2x}$

My main problem here is to choose which particular solution to use.
Since the "original equation" is = 18, should my particular solution just be the constant K? However, that doesn't suit well with the fact that $y'(0) = 1$.

Comment: take $y_p=2$ as your particular solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Hint***
$$y''(t) - 6y'(t) + 9y(t) = 18$$
$$y''(t) - 6y'(t) + 9(y(t)-2) =0$$
Substitute $ z=y-2$
then:
$$z''(t) - 6z'(t) + 9z(t) =0$$
It's homogenous now. Solve for z. And substitute back $z=y-2$

You can conclude that $y=y_h+y_p=y_h+2$